# How to get a variable to an activity which is modified by a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to solve a particular problem when I am calling another Activity from my main Activity to get the result.

My main concern is a variable in the DeviceListActivity named `bToggle`, which is being modified by a broadcast receiver, and the same variable is being sent to the `MainActivity`, which I am failing to get.

This is my `MainActivity` class which call another Activity to get the result:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public void someMethod(){
        Runnable runnableBlueDeviceList = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Intent BlueIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(BlueIntent, 13);
            }                       
        };
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // if(DEBUG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {

            case 13:
                // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device MAC adress to connect
                // But it may be alive or dead
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Get the device MAC address
                    device_address = data.getExtras().getString("device_address");
                    device_toggle = data.getIntExtra("device_toggle", 0);

                    // Attempt to connect to the device
                    if(device_toggle==1) {
                        changeMenuItem();
                    } else {
                        scanFlag=0;
                        device_address=null;
                        showToast(getApplicationContext(), "BLUTOOTH DEVICE NOT ACTIVE");
                    }   
                } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    scanFlag=0;
                    device_address = null;
                    showToast(getApplicationContext(), "BLUTOOTH CONNECTION CANCELLED, " + "\n(OR) \nBLUTOOTH DEVICE NOT COMPATIBLE");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

`DeviceListActivity` has a variable `bToggle` which is being modified by a `BroadcastReceiver` and sent to the `MainActivity` through intents:

```
    public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
        // Debugging
        private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
        private static final boolean D = true;

        // Return Intent extra

        public static int bToggle = 0; 

        // The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
        private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
                mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
                String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
                String address = " ";

                if(info.length()>16)
                    address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

                // If the text view contains no devices found then dont proceed
                if(info.contains("No devices found")) {

                } else if (address.startsWith("00")) {
                    // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("device_address", address);
                    intent.putExtra("device_toggle", bToggle);
                    // Set result and finish this Activity
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK , intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Set result CANCELED incase the user tries to connect to other devices
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        // The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
        // changes the title when discovery is finished
        private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                // When discovery finds a device
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                    if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    }
                    scanButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                    setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                    if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                        String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                        scanButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                    //Device is now connected
                    bToggle = 1;
                    showToast(getApplicationContext(), "BLUTOOTH CONNECTION SUCCESS-FULL");
                } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                   //Device has disconnected
                   bToggle = 0;
                   showToast(getApplicationContext(), "BLUTOOTH NOT-CONNECTED");
                }
            }
        };
```

So the main problem is I cannot get the variable `bToggle`

Comment: Did you try like this `int a = DeviceListActivity.bToggle` in your **MainActivity**

Comment: `which I am fail to get` - what do you mean? Are you getting errors? Please specify what's the problem.

Comment: I am not getting any error, but i cant get the variable. that means my app shows "Bluetooth connected" status even when the other bluetooth device is powered off.

Comment: If using static variables solves the problem i would have done that long ago @Tamilan